# ComboBox - can't change selection/can't select

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox

I have a xaml that has a combobox. I have items there that for some reason I can't select them and when I do choose an item it usually doesn't let me change my selection, and if it does it's only for certain values.
Here is the code:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentUsers}">
    < ComboBox.ItemsSource>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DictionaryKeyToValueConverter"} Mode="OneWay">
               < Binding Path="AllUsersByDepartment"/>
               < Binding Path = " Department"/ >
          < / MultiBinding>
     < / ComboBox.ItemsSource>
     < ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType = " { x : Type ComboBoxItem}">
              < Setter Property = " IsEnabled">
                   < Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter = "{StaticResource DictionaryKeyToValueConverter}" Mode="OneWay " / >
                             <Binding Path = " DataContext.UserToAvailabilityDictionary" RelativeSource ="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,  AncestorType = { x : Type ComboBox}}"/>
                            < Binding Path = ". "/>
                        < / MultiBinding >
                     < / Setter.Value>
                  </Setter>
             < Style.Triggers >
                 < Trigger Property="IsEnabled " Value = " False " >
                    <Setter Property = " Template">
                        < Setter.Value >
                            < ControlTemplate>
                                < TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" Foreground="Red"/>
                            < / ControlTemplate>
                        < / Setter.Value>
                      </Setter>
                 < / Trigger>
             < / Style.Triggers
         </Style >
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle >
     < ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        < DataTemplate>
            < ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
        < / DataTemplate > 
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate >
  </ComboBox>
```

I hope what I wrote is clear since I copied it from the computer to my phone.
Basically I have all the users and I divide them by departments. A user can see only ones in his department and can select ones that are available by the binded dictionary.  If not available the item in the ComboBox will be red and uunelectable. This works.  The only thing that doesnt is changing selection on some items and some items are not selectable to start with (even though they aren't colored red and should be). I changed the object of the user to always return false in the Equals method because I read that that might be the problem, but it didn't help. 
Thanks in advance.

Update: I removed the styling of the ComboBox items and the templates and I can choose anything. But I really need the triggers and the styles.

Comment: Sorry I'll try to edit the code so it shows up as a code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the ComboBox.ItemTemplate and instead put a DisplayMemberPath in the ComboBox and now it works.